# `QMesh` index buffer stride is 0

Tags: c++, qt, qt3d

I'm trying to load a triangulated `.obj` file using Qt3D's `QMesh` loader, like so:

```cpp
auto *mesh = new Qt3DRender::QMesh();
mesh->setSource(path);

connect(
  mesh,
  &Qt3DRender::QMesh::statusChanged,
  [this, mesh](Qt3DRender::QMesh::Status status) {
    if (status != Qt3DRender::QMesh::Ready) {
      return;
    }

    auto *geometry = mesh->geometry();
    auto *v_attrib = findGeometryAttribute(geometry, Qt3DCore::QAttribute::VertexAttribute);
    auto *i_attrib = findGeometryAttribute(geometry, Qt3DCore::QAttribute::IndexAttribute);

    qDebug() << "vert: count:" << v_attrib->count() << "offset:" << v_attrib->byteOffset() << "stride:" << v_attrib->byteStride();
    qDebug() << "indx: count:" << i_attrib->count() << "offset:" << i_attrib->byteOffset() << "stride:" << i_attrib->byteStride();
});
```

The results are as follows:

```
vert: count: 1089 offset: 0 stride: 48
indx: count: 6144 offset: 0 stride: 0
```

Without knowing the stride, it's very difficult to find the correct data in the buffer, and it might differ depending on the machine. I'm wondering if Qt3D is just not loading the mesh in a triangulated manner (although the blender exported `.obj` file is triangulated).

Does anyone know if the stride is guaranteed to be a particular number?

Comment: I think there's no stride because index buffers have no stride, right? So i_0, i_1, i_2 is the first triangle, then OpenGL will use the next 3 indices as triangle indices, and so on. So the stride is 3 but this is not explicitly defined for index buffers.